# History/origin of the pronunciation/spelling of "Butcher"?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation

The pronunciation of the first syllable of [butcher](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/butcher) as /ˈbʊt͡ʃ ..../ is for non-native speakers astonishing. From spelling alone, one would probably guess that it's pronunciation would be more like that of "but" /bʌt/. Surely there must be historic reasons for this (guessing sound-shifts, time of borrowing from french, etc.). What are the reasons for butcher being pronounced the way it is today?

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of words in which a 'u' is pronounced /ʊ/ even in dialects (such as South Eastern English) where it is normally /ʌ/. They all or nearly all have a labial consonant preceding it:

Eg: Pull, push, put, puss, bull, bush, full.

This is not a reliable environment: consider puck, buck, pus, putt, which have /ʌ/ in such dialects.

So there is nothing anomalous about "butcher": it belongs to an established class of words with /ʊ/

Comment: Oh, apparently Wikipedia has a more comprehensive description of the environment for the split; I quoted it in my answer here: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/254506/77227 It seems that *butcher* is regular, but I can't think of any other words like it (except *butch*), since *putch* and *futch* are not words.

Comment: @herisson no, but there is [*putcher*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/putcher) (Collins), meaning a salmon trap.  The logical (back-formed) verb *\*putch* doesn't seem to exist, though it's so common as a typo for *putsch*, and *putch* appears as slang and as a C function (from "put character" presumably)