# Why is "pint" spelt with the same last 3 letters as "hint, lint, mint, tint"?

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling

The words *hint, lint, mint, tint* are all pronunced with a short-i sound.
The vowel in *pint* is a diphthong however. Why ?

Comment: You should probably be asking, Why is *pint* spelt with the same last 3 letters as *hint, lint, mint*?  In truth, English spelling doesn't have a good way of representing long-I before two consonants.

Comment: @DavidGarner edit done, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Etymologically, *pint* relates to *paint* -- that could explain the pronunciation bias.

Comment: @Kris My dictionary relates pint to French "pinte" which has  the same meaning. What evidence is there that "pint" and "paint" are etymologically related ? The meanings diverge quite a bit.

Comment: This for one: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pint

Comment: Maybe also: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=paint

Comment: That vowel sound is common in words ending in -d rather than -t: hind and mind are straight parallels to your examples, plus lined, mined, and tined (as in a fork) with a slight spelling alteration; also bind, dined, grind, etc. So maybe it has something to do with the voicing of the stop after /n/? This article may have the seed of an answer, but the linguistics are beyond my ken, so maybe not: *English Postnasal Stop Deletion: *NT vs. *ND∗* by Abby Kaplan http://home.utah.edu/~u0703432/CV/phorum112006.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, I have found no reference that explains this, so what follows is my own speculation and might be totally off-base. I think this has to do with the etymological origin of these words. The words *[hint](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=hint), [lint](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=lint&allowed_in_frame=0),* and *[mint](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=mint&allowed_in_frame=0)* all come from Old English. The word *[tint](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=tint&allowed_in_frame=0)* is apparently from Latin, with influences from Italian.

The word *[pint](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pint&allowed_in_frame=0)* comes from Old/Middle French *pinte* (the sources I've looked at differ in the  terminology). It seems that in many cases, vowels in Middle French words were taken into Middle English as long vowels even when they were followed by consonant clusters which would normally indicate a short pronunciation. I wrote an answer about the pronunciation of *tomb* that I think is relevant: [Why do “bomb” and “tomb” have different pronunciations?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/322076/77227)

I know of no other words from French (or actually, of any origin) that rhyme with *pint,* but you can see this tendency to use a long value before *nt* in words with other vowels that were borrowed from Old or Middle French:

- -**ount**: *[mount](http://mount), [count](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=count&allowed_in_frame=0), [fount](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fount&allowed_in_frame=0)(ain)* from Old/Middle Fr. *monter, conter, font(aine)*

  (although on the other hand, we do have *[front](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=front&allowed_in_frame=0)* with a short vowel from Old French *front,* and *font* with a different short vowel as a more recent borrowing from French)
- -**aunt**: *[haunt](http://haunt), [taunt](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=taunt&allowed_in_frame=0), [daunt](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=daunt&allowed_in_frame=0), [avaunt](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=avaunt&allowed_in_frame=0)* from Old/Middle Fr. *hanter, tanter* or *tant, danter, avant*

  (although on the other hand, we do have *[grant](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=grant&allowed_in_frame=0)* with a short vowel, and *aunt* which may have a short vowel depending on your accent)

You can see that there are a number of counter-examples where the vowel is pronounced short in Modern English. There is even one spelled with -**int**: *print,* from French *preinte/prente.* This weakens this explanation, but it still seems the most likely reason to me.

As for why we still spell it with *i*... as David Garner mentions in a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/334657/why-is-pint-spelt-with-the-same-last-3-letters-as-hint-lint-mint-tint/343573#comment765403_334657), one of the oddities of the modern English spelling system is that there is no commonly used digraph that represents the diphthong /aɪ/ ("long i"). Words like *[feast](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=feast&allowed_in_frame=0)* and *[roast](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=roast&allowed_in_frame=0)* (from French *feste* and *rostir*) ended up being spelled with the digraphs "ea" and "oa" that represented "long e" and "long o" respectively. But there isn't any clear way in the modern English spelling system to spell "pint" to indicate the length of the vowel.

- *Peint* would be just as ambiguous and irregular (it looks like it should rhyme with *feint*)
- *Pighnt* would be less ambiguous, but it doesn't fit in with the normal distribution of the trigraph *igh,* which usually only occurs at the end of a syllable or before the letter *t.* The trigraph *igh* is also rare; as the spelling suggests, it originally represented a vowel-consonant sequence rather than a pure vowel, and this is its etymological origin in most modern English words that contain "igh." There are a few words where it is used unetymologically, such as *[delight](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=delight)* (from Old French *delit*), but this arose from the analogy of all the other words ending in *-ight*; there are no existing words ending in *-ighnt* that could provide a basis for using this spelling for /aɪnt/.

The same ambiguity applies to *i* in other words, such *Christ* (doesn't rhyme with *mist*) and all the words ending in *-ind* that don't rhyme with the noun *wind.*