# Blood/roof and so on

Tags: questions

I have a question, which I have been thinking about the last 50 years. I know, that the word "blood" is prononcued "blaad" and I know. that "roof" is prononcued "ruuf", boot like "buut" , tool like "tuul". They all have 2 oo, which gives "UU", but why is blood then "blaad" and not "bluud".? Do you understand me. :)

Best regards

Kurt
Denmark

Comment: Pronunciation is **never** properly standard in English - words are how you *spell* things, not necessarily how you *say* them. Sorry about that, on behalf of every native speaker to every non-native speaker!

Comment: Related: [Why are there 3 different ways to pronounce “oo”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36905)

Comment: Spoken language is primary. It is not letters that are pronounced. It is sounds that get encoded in writing. But the spelling also encodes a multitude of other factors. Most notably etymology. You do not want to spell *history* completely differently from *historian*, and you do not want to spell the noun *access* completely differently from the verb *access*. Conversely, you might want to distinguish between *merry*, *marry*, and *Mary*, even if you pronounce all three exactly the same.

Comment: And then of course all dialects and indeed all individual people have their pronunciation quirks. You do not want the word *blood* to be spelled ten different ways depending on how it's pronounced. You want just one standard spelling. And that's what you have. *This is not something peculiar to English*, so @marcellothearcane's apologies are misinformed and misplaced. This is what happens in all languages, in all writing systems. Words are not spelled phonetically. Anywhere. Ever. You just listed one random example of a general phenomenon that affects absolutely all words.

Comment: Related: [Why does the ending -ough have six pronunciations?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/31991/) [Why do “bomb” and “tomb” have different pronunciations?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/320512/) [Why is ‘i’ in milk pronounced differently from ‘i’ in find?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/202355/) [Why are “put” and “but” different in their pronunciation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/105081/)