# When does 'gi' sound like 'ji'?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, phonemes

Let us take, *ginger*, we actually pronounce it as /[ˈdʒɪndʒə](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ginger)/ (jinjer). But take, giggling, we pronounce it as /[ˈɡɪɡ(ə)lɪŋ](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/giggling)/. There are numerous examples of this, and this confuses me a lot. So, how do I  know which pronunciation in these kinds of words is actually correct?

Comment: English orthography does not attempt to represent the sounds of English speech in any kind of one-to-one relationship. There are quite simply no hard-and-fast rules. Also, unless by _ginning_ you’re referring to the archaic, poetic variant of _beginning_, that too is pronounced as ‘jinning’.

Comment: I don't know what "ginning" is, except as related to the word "gin" in which case it is also pronounced with a "j" sound.

Comment: @DigitalChris - 'ginning' could be running a load of cotton through a cotton gin.  As to the rest, I know of no rule as to when g's are hard or soft.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no strict rules for when the letter <G> is pronounced /dʒ/ as in *ginger* and when it is pronounced /g/ as in *giggle*. In general, it is more likely to be pronounced to /dʒ/ if it is followed by <I>, <E> or <Y>, but there are many exceptions.

If you're unsure about a word, you have to look it up in a dictionary and memorize it.

Comment: Letters are not pronounced; letters are **read**. It's **phonemes** that are pronounced. If you stop thinking of letters as representing sounds, you'll do better.

Comment: @JohnLawler this is a distinction I long ago gave up on trying to make for a nontechnical audience. Insisting on making it just makes you sound cranky

Comment: So continue, if you like. Nontechnical audiences don't deserve to know facts, after all; they're content with  their prejudices already.

Comment: To my mind, someone who is asking about which pedal makes the car accelerate and which makes it slow down doesn't really need a preliminary lecture on relativity or how internal combustion engines work.

Comment: Just my take: John Lawler's comment about phonemes is what makes this a so-called ELU question. If the answer is a mere "check the dictionary; that's the only way to know for sure," then this may as well be migrated to [ell.se].

Comment: I asked a question previously http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/88238/do-hull-and-full-rhyme-rules-for-short-u-sounds-before-l and the answer was that there is a way to guess based on spelling whether the vowel from a word with UL would be STRUT or FOOT. Sometimes there is a way to predict; sometimes there is not.

Comment: Actually, letters began by representing sounds. It was thought that you needed different letters to represent different sounds, for that reason we have the Cyrillic alphabet. At some point it was realized that Roman letters, with modifications, can express sounds in any language, even tonal languages (this is a broad statement and given the variety of languages, let's say it's at best 90% correct). It is because of this anomaly that it wasn't until the 12th century that a sorting device now known as alphabetical order could be used to sort information.

Comment: The spelling of an English word is a merely a *clue* hinting to its actual pronunciation.