# The spelling "ui" and the pronunciation /uː/ in juice, fruit, bruise, cruise, sluice, suit, nuisance, recruit, bruit

Tags: orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling, linguistics, historical-change, yod-dropping

The words *juice, fruit, bruise, cruise, sluice, suit, pursuit, suitcase, lawsuit, nuisance, recruit, bruit* are spelled with *ui* and pronounced with the IPA phoneme /uː/.

Full pronunciations from *OED*:

> *nuisance*: Brit. /ˈnjuːsns/,  U.S. /ˈn(j)us(ə)ns/ 
>   *juice*:         Brit.  /dʒuːs/,  U.S. /dʒus/ 
>   *cruise*:      Brit.   /kruːz/,  U.S. /kruz/ 
>   *bruise*:      Brit.   /bruːz/,  U.S. /bruz/ 
>   *suit*:           Brit.   /s(j)uːt/,  U.S. /sut/ 
>   *recruit*:     Brit.    /rᵻˈkruːt/,  U.S. /rəˈkrut/, /riˈkrut/ 
>   *fruit*:         Brit.  /fruːt/,  U.S. /frut/ 
>   *sluice:*       Brit. /sluːs/,  U.S. /slus/ 
>   *bruit:*        Brit.    /bruːt/,  U.S. /brut/ (In sense 5   also) Brit. /ˈbruːi/,  U.S. /ˈbrui/

The pronunciation differs from some other similar words spelled with *ui* like *guise, disguise, guide, cuisine, suicide*.

Full pronunciations from *OED*:

> *guide:*       Brit. /ɡʌɪd/,  U.S. /ɡaɪd/ 
>   *guise:*       Brit.  /ɡʌɪz/,  U.S. /ɡaɪz/ 
>   *cuisine:*   /kwiːˈziːn/ 
>   *suicide:*   /ˈs(j)uːɪsʌɪd/

*Ruin* is kind of an exception to an exception because the pronunciation is different in British English and American English:

Full pronunciations from *OED*:

> *ruin:* Brit.  /ˈruːɪn/,  U.S. /ˈruən/, /ˈruˌɪn/

Note: There can be other similar words I might have missed and there can be dialectal/regional differences also.

When I checked the etymology of the word *sluice* in *OED*, I found this note:

> The spelling with *ui* (compare *juice*) did not come into general use until the 18th century.

In fact, when you check the older (pre-1600s) spellings of the word *sluice* in *OED*, you can see that it is mostly spelled with *u* instead of *ui*. (Of course, there are other irregular spellings also). In *OED*, the first citation where the word is spelled with *ui* is from 1611. The word is written as *sluice* which is same as today and the citation is from Randle Cotgrave · A dictionarie of the French and English tongues · 1st edition.

In *OED*, the etymology of the word doesn't mention the *ui* spelling also (except the current Dutch word *sluis*):

> < Old French *escluse* (*-clusse , -clouse* , etc.; modern French *écluse* ), = Spanish *esclusa* , Portuguese *esclusa* , late and medieval Latin *exclusa* (also *sclusa* , etc.), feminine singular of Latin *exclūsus* , past participle of *exclūdere* to shut out, exclude v. 
>   <sub>Old French is also the source of Middle Dutch *sluse , sluyse , sluus* (Dutch *sluis* , West Frisian *slús* ), Middle Low German *sluse , sluze* (Low German *slüse , slüs* , German *schleuse* ), Danish *sluse* , Swedish *slus* . For the English forms which represent the late Latin *clūsa* see *clow* n.1</sub>

Historical spellings of *sluice* from *OED*:

> α. 
>   1340: scluse 
>   1449: Scluces
>   c1480: scluse
>   1558: sklus
>   1583: scluse
>   1609: scluces
>   1665 : Scluse
>   β.
>   1533: slewssis
>   1541–2: sloweses
>   1582: sleuss 
>   ?1677: slewces
>   γ.
>   1538: sluse
>   1568: slus
>   1577: Sluse
>   1611: sluce
>   1648: Sluses
>   1695: Sluces
>   δ.
>   1596: Sluyce
>   1611: Sluice
>   1699: sluice
>   1745: Sluices
>   1785: sluices
>   1839: sluice
>   1879: sluices 
>   1794: sluices

You can see a similar pattern for *juice*, *bruise* and somewhat *cruise* also.

In *OED,* the first citation where *juice* is spelled as today is from a1626.

Etymology of *juice* from OED:

> < French *jus*, < Latin *jūs* broth, sauce, juice of animal or plant. The β forms are normal from French; with the others compare those of *duke, flute, jupe, and bruit, fruit*.

*OED* has the note below in the etymology of *cruise*:

> The word is thus ultimately identical with *croise v. and cross v.*; the current spelling with *ui* seems to be after Dutch; but the vowel sound is as in Spanish and Portuguese.

Although there isn't an exact pattern, the historical spelling change pattern explained above differs in the words like *suit, fruit, recruit* but the question and the answer might cover them also. The words in the question is mostly the ones where it has the *ui* spelling followed by *ce* and *se*.

After all these historical notes, what is the question?

### Why was *ui* spelling introduced in words that used to be spelled with *u* and where the pronunciation is with IPA phoneme /uː/?

Why did it become more prevalent after 18th century?

Note: I know that historical "why" questions are hard to answer. English has a lot of irregularities and changes throughout the history also. There isn't an exact pattern or rule in spelling and orthography; but the spelling is mostly fixed in the traditional orthography.

- The answer might be related to the English spelling reforms or how Dutch influenced the spelling of the words in these reforms or in the history.
- Or is there any influential person or publication that might have affected these spellings?
- Or might the spelling of the word *fruit* or any other word have influenced the words like *juice, sluice*? *Fruit* is an older word but it has historical spellings like *frut* and the first citation with *fruit* is from 1549 in *OED*.
- Was there a need or a proposition of indicating longer *u* sound in the spelling reforms?

Comment: For the most part, each word has its own history, and the older the more complicated. So while we can of course blame the Dutch for *duiker* and *Kuiper* Belt like *buy*, more ancient words are going to be more complex to trace out. Are you interested only in why particular words spelled ‹ui› have only /u/ there, or are you also interested in those spelled that way but have something else? Many you mention are tied up in the conventions for pronouncing Latin or Romance imports in English, including the Western Romance orthographic custom of using ‹gu› to indicate an unpalatalized "hard" /g/ .

Comment: Just pronouncing the GUI letter-sequence has many disparate tales to tell: *guilt, guile, guild, guitar, guinea, guidon, roguish, penguin, languid, anguish, sanguine, linguine, inguinal, aiguille, guillemot, fatiguing, prologuize, haranguing, guillotine, linguistics, distinguish, cataloguing*.

Comment: This question has too many moving parts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Words with "gui" like "guide" and "guise" don't contain the "ui" digraph: instead, they have the "gu" digraph that functions to mark "hard g" before a front vowel letter (I or E).

The word *suicide* doesn't contain the "ui" digraph either: it has U followed by I in hiatus. This is the usual pronunciation of "ui" before a consonant letter in words from Latin, like *suicide* (from latin *suicida*).

#### Further background information about the "ui" digraph

As a digraph, "ui" acts as an alternative spelling of the "long u" sound in English. The basic pronunciation of the "long u" sound is /juː/, but because of "[yod-dropping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_consonant_clusters#Yod-dropping)", the pronunciation /uː/ is used instead after /dʒ/ or /r/, or after a consonant cluster ending in /l/. The current pronunciations of the English "long u" sound are thought to have developed from a falling diphthong pronounced something like [ɪu̯]. The diphthong [ɪu̯] had several different sources:

- various diphthongs in native English words
- words from French that had in that language the front rounded monophthong /y/
- words from French with various diphthongs, such as *beauty, deuce, suit* from French *beawté/beuté/bewté, deux, siute/sute/seute/suite*

In [modern Dutch, "ui"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_orthography#Sound_to_spelling_correspondences) is used as a digraph representing a front rounded diphthong typically transcribed /œy̯/. This sound developed from an earlier long monophthong, as exemplified by the Dutch word *bruin* from Proto-Germanic *brūnaz (English *brown*). If the Dutch word *sluis* was borrowed from French before the  diphthongization of long high vowels, that would explain why it has "ui".

The various changes that occurred between diphthongs and monophthongal long vowels, between and within languages, probably contributed to the diversity of spellings of the "long u" sound in present-day English.

#### The words *bruise, juice* and *cruise*

The word *bruise* is an unusual "ui" word in that it has a Germanic origin. The "ui" here is thought to have developed irregularly or dialectally from an Old English [yː] sound, which in most words lost its rounding (e.g. Old English [myːs] became modern English *mice* /maɪs/ via a Middle English form /miːs/). I talk a little bit more about it in [my answer to the question "Relation of RUFFLER and RUYFLER"](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/392765/77227).

With *cruise,* as the OED mentions, it seems pretty likely that the spelling was just taken from Dutch. Although the OED entry mentions *cruse* as a historical alternative spelling, I don't think it says that *cruse* used to be the more common spelling: both spellings (as well as *cruize*) are marked as being used starting from the 17th century. The pronunciation with /uː/ could be related to the pronunciation of  Spanish/Portuguese *cruzar,* or it could be based on the spelling.

I don't know of any special reason for why the spelling *juice* won out over spellings like *juce* or *juse.* Neither of those spellings has any particular issue with representing the sound of the word: *-⁠uce* and *-⁠use* are used in the spelling of some words that rhyme with *juice,* such as *puce, spruce, truce, reduce, use, abuse.* Your suggestion of influence from other words spelled with "ui" seems the best explanation to me. I don't know of any way Dutch could have influenced the spelling of *juice*, since I haven't found any Dutch words spelled with *ui* that are related to French *jus* or English *juice.*

I'm not sure about the history of the spelling *sluice.*

Comment: French had *fruit, fruition* < Latin *frūctus, fruitiōnem*.

Comment: To clarify, English **today** does not have an [ɪu̯] falling diphthong; it has a [i̯u] rising diphthong. So writing without diacritics, that’s just /ju/ today, not the hypothesized /iw/ version *d’antan*. :)

Comment: Recently I have been wondering the same question, but what about the word fluid?

Comment: @sebas: "fluid" is like "suicide": an u sound followed by an i sound, in separate syllables.