# Pronunciation of "skull"

Tags: pronunciation

I have listened to the pronunciation of the word skull  in both Oxford and Longman Dictionaries AE and BE.

I do not feel that u in skull is pronounced like the u in cup ,it is more similar to the oo in book.

Is there a reason for that ?

Comment: Almost all English speakers will pronounce it with u as in cup, not oo as in book.

Comment: The Oxford BrE pronunciations of [skull](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/skull) and [book](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/book) sound very different, and quite accurate. More to the point of your question is why do you not feel that *skull* is pronounced like *cup*?

Comment: @Rani2Add I think you mean something between *"ɔ"* and *"æ"*. Yes?

Comment: Do "skull" and "bull" (or [any of these words](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Rhymes:English/%CA%8Al)) rhyme for you?

Comment: I think your question is kind of related to [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/88238/do-hull-and-full-rhyme-rules-for-short-u-sounds-before-l). Is it?

Comment: Using OALD skull does rhyme with bull for me . While blood does not rhyme with hood . I think that L has some effect in altering the previous sounds

Comment: Collins Online Dictionary gives two pronunciations for the word skull one is like bull the other is like blood .

Answer (score 1):

Have a listen to the pronunciation on [American Heritage Dictionary](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=skull&submit.x=0&submit.y=0). They write it as `(skŭl)`, using the same symbol as their vowel in "cup" (`kŭp`).

I've heard the pronunciation vary by region and culture across the US, sometimes like the vowel in "cup", sometimes as in "book", sometimes as in "coal".

There's something about vowels being followed by the letter L.

- Consider also words like "pull", "bull", "cull", "hull", "skulk", "folk", "yolk", "caulk", etc.
- See also the "*Full–fool* merger" and "*Hull–hole* merger" sections of Wikipedia's article ["English-language vowel changes before historic /l/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_vowel_changes_before_historic_/l/#Modern_L-vocalization).

Comment: There is an interesting earlier question on this site from an American speaker with a merger of the "cup" and "book" vowels before L: [Do “hull” and “full” rhyme?— rules for “short U” sounds before L](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/88238/do-hull-and-full-rhyme-rules-for-short-u-sounds-before-l)